# How to let the user paste an URL into TextFormfield and when displayed this URL can be clicked? in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a Social app which allow user to write post and some text...
I want increase the engagement and let the user paste an URL into the TextFormfield along with other thext and when this URL is displayed can be launched into the browser.
How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this library out. It does exactly what you want. Let me know if you want some sample code though this library has some code with it
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify

Comment: Would be great a code example to be implemented into TextFormField

Comment: Oh my fault I thought you wanted it for normal text. I am going to have to look into this library to see how to do it for textFormFields